# how to get cell index in extjs datepicker for selected date?

Tags: css, date, extjs

I want to show bgcolor dynamically to selected date. for date I have used datepicker as xtype in extjs.

```
{
    xtype:'datepicker',
    id:'monthEventId'
}
```

when I select the date I have function in controller to get selected date:-

```
               selctEventDate: function (picker, date) {
                   eventDate = date;
                   datePicker = picker;
                   this.showColor(date);
                   txtNodeLength = picker.cells.elements.length;
               },

               monthEventView.textNodes[0].innerText = "hello";
```

this line of code displays the hello string in first cell of calendar.but I want the index number of selected date so that I can set string/text to that cell directly.in console it shows 42 number of textnodes like this:-

```
                          textNodes: Array[42]
                          0: span
                          1: span
```

how to getselected cell node number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to give backgroung color & text to the selected date in datepicker in extjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634493/how-to-give-backgroung-color-text-to-the-selected-date-in-datepicker-in-extjs)

Comment: Take a look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659702/extjs-4-datepicker-coloring-cells) solution. It isn't perfect, but it works.